# Callback after Ajax form submit by Drupal 8 form

Tags: ajax, drupal-8

I have one Drupal 8 form (ID: regform) and I have to done some JS triggers after the form AJAX submit.

For example form contains choose plan field, after form submit, I have to display some calculated price in the other block in the same page, So I am trying to pick a callback function after Ajax submit. What I have to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you can use the below code to resolve your issue. You can add this snippet to a javascript file which located in your custom theme or module.

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.custom = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {
        if (settings.data && settings.data.indexOf("form_id=regform") != -1) {
          //your code here
        }
      });
    }
  }
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

Comment: it does not work on drupal 9, this function never get called    $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me in **Drupal 9.2.10**: *(December 2021)*

```
jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
  if (settings.data.indexOf( "form_id=modal_test_form") != -1) {
    console.log('Hello!');
  }
});
```